# What are your best resources for winding custom transformers?

Tags: transformer, documentation

What are the best resources that you have found for winding custom transformers?

prose, videos, forums, etc.

I am looking for things more on the practical side rather than resources explaining the basics of transformer winding ratios. Once I get enough responses, I will compile them into a list. I purposely did not differentiate between power and signal transformers, so I am hoping to get some of both.

For instance, here are a few of mine:

https://sound-au.com/xfmr.htm
http://www.ieee.li/pdf/introduction_to_power_electronics/chapter_15.pdf
http://www.coilcraft-cps.com/pdf/doc857_Multiple_Applications.pdf
http://www.jensen-transformers.com/an/Audio%20Transformers%20Chapter.pdf

Comment: My best resource (by a mile) is "me" but it depends on how many you are going to build.

Comment: Working for a transformer manufacturer is also handy, and can shift the balance regarding "how many".

Comment: My specific application is building a 1:1 wide bandwidth isolation transformer for instrumentation purposes. I will only be winging 1 or 2, but I agree on the higher volume case.

Answer (score 6):

As from my experience:

1. You have to make a form (probably a wooden form) which is exactly the form of the transformer core, but longer.
2. For convenience make a winding rig - a place to attach the form connected with a handle and a shaft for wire spool. Wire spool has to have some kind of breaking mechanism attached to you get some tension on the wire.
3. Make a sheet of plywood with a hole exactly the shape of the form - you will use it slide the finished coil from the form.
4. Wrap a form with a thin cardboard, leave edges of the cardboard so that you can fold them and glue them together after you finish the winding.

The idea is that you attach a form to a handle, put a plywood sheet on it, then put cardboard, then wind the wire, fold cardboard around and use a plywood sheet to pull the coil off the form. Cover the form with soap or paraffin so the coil will slide off more easily.

This is all I have in terms of photos, please excuse the quality and incomprehension.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]